# Display a Variable in MessageBox c++

Tags: c++, windows, messagebox

How to display a Variable in MessageBox c++ ?

```
string name = "stackoverflow";

MessageBox(hWnd, "name is: <string name here?>", "Msg title", MB_OK | MB_ICONQUESTION);
```

I want to show it in the following way (#1):

```
"name is: stackoverflow"
```

---

and this?

```
int id = '3';

MessageBox(hWnd, "id is: <int id here?>", "Msg title", MB_OK | MB_ICONQUESTION);
```

and I want to show it in the following way (#2):

```
id is: 3
```

**how to do this with c++ ?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a temporary buffer to store your string in and use `sprintf`, change the formatting depending on your variable type. For your first example the following should work:

```
 char buff[100];
 string name = "stackoverflow";
 sprintf_s(buff, "name is:%s", name.c_str());
 cout << buff;
```

Then call message box with buff as the string argument

```
MessageBox(hWnd, buff, "Msg title", MB_OK | MB_ICONQUESTION);
```

for an int change to:

```
int d = 3;
sprintf_s(buff, "name is:%d",d);
```

Comment: I've change sprintf to sprintf_s, and code working correctly
**Thank you very much**

Comment: to show appreciation accept the answer by clicking the green check below the number.

Comment: @Gaspa79 Erm you're not supposed to include winuser.h directly. Per the docs, [`#include <Windows.h>` instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox).

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with a macro

```
#define MSGBOX(x) \
{ \
   std::ostringstream oss; \
   oss << x; \
   MessageBox(oss.str().c_str(), "Msg Title", MB_OK | MB_ICONQUESTION); \
}
```

To use

```
string x = "fred";
int d = 3;
MSGBOX("In its simplest form");
MSGBOX("String x is " << x);
MSGBOX("Number value is " << d);
```

Alternatively, you can use varargs (the old fashioned way: not the C++11 way which I haven't got the hang of yet)

```
void MsgBox(const char* str, ...)
{
    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl, str);
    char buff[1024];  // May need to be bigger
    vsprintf(buff, str, vl);
    MessageBox(buff, "MsgTitle", MB_OK | MB_ICONQUESTION);
}
string x = "fred";
int d = 3;
MsgBox("In its simplest form");
MsgBox("String x is %s", x.c_str());
MsgBox("Number value is %d", d);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the only one that worked for me:

```
std::string myString = "x = ";
int width = 1024;
myString += std::to_string(width);

LPWSTR ws = new wchar_t[myString.size() + 1];
copy(myString.begin(), myString.end(), ws);
ws[myString.size()] = 0; // zero at the end

MessageBox(NULL, ws, L"Windows Tutorial", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not good to see people still messing with buffers. That was unnecessary in 1998, and definitely today.

```
std::string name = "stackoverflow";

MessageBox(hWnd, ("name is: "+name).c_str(), "Msg title", MB_OK | MB_ICONQUESTION);
```

If you're using Unicode (which makes sense in the 21st century)

```
std::wstring name = L"stackoverflow";

MessageBox(hWnd, (L"name is: "+name).c_str(), L"Msg title", MB_OK | MB_ICONQUESTION);
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question:

string name = 'stackoverflow';

MessageBox("name is: "+name , "Msg title", MB_OK | MB_ICONQUESTION);

do in same way for others.

Comment: i try this

 `std::string mynm = "stackoverflow";

 MessageBox(hWnd, L"name is: "+mynm, L"Msg title", MB_OK | MB_ICONQUESTION);`

but the error is

 1 **IntelliSense: no operator "+" matches these operands operand types are: const wchar_t [10] + std::string**

Comment: remove L from statement

Comment: This is flat-out wrong. The + operator does not concatenate string literals in C++; it performs pointer arithmetic.